# How can I quantify (with numbers) an incoming webcam stream with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, navigator

I want to quantify the incoming webcam stream with numbers so that I can hash it. A generalized version of this would be how can I quantify a webcam stream with text.
I'm currently using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` to get the incoming video stream.
My end goal is to successfully take the incoming video stream, quantify it somehow, and get a bunch of random data. So far I only have `getUserMedia` by itself:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
.then(function(stream) {
  console.log(stream)
})
.catch(function(err) {
  /* handle the error */
});
```

Comment: That's really not clear what you wish to do... Do you need to be able to rebuild the data back afterward? What's the end goal? Maybe a RNG? Solutions will depend on these, but there is no real way to access the raw data anyway (there isn't a well defined raw data format for MediaStreams). However, you can generate a compressed media using the MediaRecorder, or you can capture the video's bitmap through the ImageCapture API (or <video> + <canvas>) or the audio's data through the WebAudioAPI. But none of these will really be the raw data...

Comment: The end goal is to have data to use in a RNG, yes. There is no need to rebuild the data afterwards. I already have the mic data quantified, I just need the video data.